# Why can CLion run my program but I cannot? [Could not find procedure entry point...]

Tags: c++, dll, mingw, box2d

CLion can run my executable fine when it builds it. However, if I were to open my built executable via double-clicking it in file explorer, it gives:

```
Entry Point Not Found

The procedure entry point _ZdlPvj could not be located in the dynamic link library
<Path-to-dll>/libBox2D.dll
```

I've built libBox2D.dll from source with MingW too. There are no other copies of libBox2D.dll in any of my PATH directories. I am at a loss.

I'm on Windows compiling with Mingw using make. If any more information is needed I will happily provide it.

Cheers

[Edit] libBox2D.dll is located in the same directory as my executable.

Comment: is `libBox2D.dll` located in the same directory as executable?

Comment: @user7860670 Yup it is.

Comment: *CLion can run my executable fine when it builds it* -- do you mean you can run the exe from inside CLion, but not from cmd?

Comment: @Roy2511 Yes that's correct. In-fact, running my executable via cmd doesn't even return any error messages or anything.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your environment rather than a programming issue, so probably off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Sweet so it turns out I was just missing MinGW's DLL's: libgg_s_dw2-1.dll and libstdc++-6.dll.

Putting them alongside my executable fixed the issue.